# Trying to access protected member in derived class using base class object

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

This line gives error: Cannot access protected member   `BaseClass.number` via a qualifier of type `BaseClass`,the qualifier must be of type `DerivedClass` (or derived from it) can someone help me with this . see the code below
thanks in adavance

```
using System;
public class BaseClass
{
    protected int number = 10;
}
public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{   
    public void Print()
    {
        BaseClass obj = new BaseClass();
        //Console.WriteLine(obj.number); 
    // we get error if we try to print why?
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass obj2 = new DerivedClass();
        obj2.Print();
    }
}
```

but why does compiler gives error.
why this way of calling method is wrong

Comment: [protected keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected) - *A protected member of a base class is accessible in a derived class only if the access occurs through the derived class type.* - does it answer your question?

Comment: instead of doing obj.number use this.number

Comment: @Rafalon It can be accessed with in the class it is defined as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to mirror [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected#example) in the docs.

> A protected member of a base class is accessible in a derived class only if the access occurs through the derived class type.

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{   
    public void Print()
    {
        BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass();
        DerivedClass derived = new DerivedClass();

        // This is ok
        Console.WriteLine(number); 

        // So is this
        Console.WriteLine(derived.number);

        // But you can't do this
        Console.WriteLine(baseClass.number); 
    }
}
```

Without this restriction in place the following would be possible, which is clearly a security flaw:

```
public class AnotherDerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public bool IsValid => number == 10;
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{   
    public void Print()
    {
        BaseClass anotherAsBase = new AnotherDerivedClass();

        anotherAsBase.number = 0;
    }
}
```

In the above example, an instance of `DerivedClass` has interfered with the implementation details of `AnotherDerivedClass`. As `DerivedClass` is a completely different type to `AnotherDerivedClass`, it shouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: yes, but do you know why we can't do in that way. why are we restricted from doing that way?

Comment: @AkhilKarankoti I've added a reason why the restriction is in place.

Comment: Can you explain me why it is a security flaw?

Comment: @AkhilKarankoti because it would allow `DerivedClass` to access a protected member of `AnotherDerivedClass` even though they are completely different types. Imagine the implementation of `AnotherDerivedClass` had logic that required `number`, but an instance of `DerivedClass` was able to change the value of `number`.

Comment: I understood that you meant to say that 'number' in 'DerivedClass' and 'number' in 'AnotherDerivedClass' are same?. They are entirely different. So even if you change 'number' in one class it wouldn't effect in another class as they are different instances.

Comment: @AkhilKarankoti Maybe my example wasn't clear enough. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
public class BaseClass
{
    protected int number = 10;
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public void Print()
    {
        this.number = 20;  // you access it as a private filed 

    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass obj2 = new DerivedClass();
        obj2.Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, we can do like that but out of curiosity why cant we do in that way (as above code )of accessing is what i need

Comment: @AkhilKarankoti stackoverflow is made for asking a question if you have problem understanding it and not for questioning why things work as they do.
Stop down voting answers.

Comment: Man Im eager to find out why. And coming to your voting. Im a new user i did not  get access to voting yet.